# Android which activity resumed after crash

Tags: android, android-activity, crash

When my app crashes always the activity 2-3 activities back is started. Why is this? Can I change this to start always the most recent activity (before the crashing one, of course)?

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit.!

Comment: What else do you need? It's a short question, I can't think about anything more to say.

Comment: is it force closing or restarting?

Comment: It crashes. It shows the usual crash dialog "app stopped working" I click ok and then it (re)starts 2-3 activities before.

Comment: what do you want to say in the first line. _When my app crashes always the activity 2-3 activities back is started._

Comment: post the logcat or the code, where the app crashes.

Comment: I'm crashing it manually, just to check this. What I mean: when the activity crashes I expect the app restarts in the last "working" activity, but it starts like 2-3 activities before, and I'm wondering why.

Comment: Do you use any flags when you start an activity?

Comment: why dont you use START_STICKY to start from the last activity, i mean the activity that was recently opened when the activity was force closed.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you called `finish()` method in the activity which is calling next activity which get crashed. Try to remove that finish() method from the calling activity.

Comment: Not the case. Checked in all my project and I have a few finish() calls, but none is called in the activity stacks I'm talking about.

Comment: can you post some code like how you called the activity before app crashes?

Comment: Usual way... `context.startActivity(intent);`